# Superman time-travels to red Sun age

Tags: dc, time-travel, comics, superman, episode-identification

I have a rather vague recollection of this comic book. I believe I read this in early 70's. Superman time-travels back to the time when the Sun is a red star. The Earth is (rather strangely) inhabited by human beings in a savage stage. Because the Sun is red, Superman lost all his super-powers. I am not able to recollect the plot further. I am looking for the tittle of this comic and if possible front cover, and/or a couple of frames from the comic book.

Comment: The sun would never be a red star in the prehistory of the Earth. It would have only been red in the FAR future...

Answer (score 6):

#### Action Comics #300 (1963) - Superman Under the Red Sun

[Hereafter](http://dcanimated.wikia.com/wiki/Hereafter), where Superman is shunted into a barren, uninhabited Earth under a red sun in a distant future through the actions of a Superman Revenge Squad shows similarities to "Superman Under the Red Sun", the leading story in Action Comics #300 (1963).

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: This could be it !! But as I remember it, Superman travels  into the past not the future - but then my memory of this comic is very vague. I am sure that If I could ever find this one also, I would love to read it.

Comment: Definitely, one of the best Superman stories ever!

Comment: The sun wouldn't be red in the past, only in the future. A yellow star is a relatively young to middle-aged star, whereas a red star is the swollen stage of an older, dying star.

Answer (score 2):

There's a Justice League episode, [Hereafter](http://dcanimated.wikia.com/wiki/Hereafter), which is based upon this story.

[image: Superman, under a red sun, had to make do with what he could find/make.]

I'm unable to find a reference to the title of the original story, though.

There aren't humans in this future (other than the immortal Vandal Savage), though there are somewhat intelligent beings who inhabit the world, evolved from creatures who survived the apocalypse.

Comment: In both cases, things seem to turn out better than the story where Superman ends up in the far future, fighting robot's with the copied mind of Batman, controlled by the twin clones of Adolf Hitler who became immortal after winning WW2 in the early 21st century. ( Yes, it's complicated. No, it's a real thing ).